# Limiting number of parallel jobs in Azure DevOps Pipeline YAML

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Our team is creating a Azure DevOps Pipeline using the YAML Schema to run our test scripts, running multiple iterations of the same test scripts. **How can I tell the job to run the same test 8 times, but limit the maximum number of tests running in parallel to 3?**

The Azure DevOps [YAML Schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#strategies) shows a way to limit the number of parallel runs for a matrix of runs:

```
job: Build
strategy:
  maxParallel: 2
  matrix:
    Python35:
      PYTHON_VERSION: '3.5'
    Python36:
      PYTHON_VERSION: '3.6'
```

But trying something like

```
job: Build
strategy:
  maxParallel: 2
  parallel: 8
```

throws an error, saying that parallel is an unexpected identifier.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bit late but still want to provide an answer for others.
If you check the following documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#define-a-single-job

It talks about the full spec of YAML jobs:

```yaml
- job: string  # name of the job, A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore
  displayName: string  # friendly name to display in the UI
  dependsOn: string | [ string ]
  condition: string
  strategy:
    parallel: # parallel strategy
    matrix: # matrix strategy
    maxParallel: number # maximum number simultaneous matrix legs to run
    # note: `parallel` and `matrix` are mutually exclusive
    # you may specify one or the other; including both is an error
    # `maxParallel` is only valid with `matrix`
  continueOnError: boolean  # 'true' if future jobs should run even if this job fails; defaults to 'false'
  pool: pool # agent pool
  workspace:
    clean: outputs | resources | all # what to clean up before the job runs
  container: containerReference # container to run this job inside
  timeoutInMinutes: number # how long to run the job before automatically cancelling
  cancelTimeoutInMinutes: number # how much time to give 'run always even if cancelled tasks' before killing them
  variables: { string: string } | [ variable | variableReference ] 
  steps: [ script | bash | pwsh | powershell | checkout | task | templateReference ]
  services: { string: string | container } # container resources to run as a service container
```

it states the `'parallel' and 'matrix' are mutually exclusive`. This means you can use maxParallel only with the matrix strategy. Without matrix you have to use "parallel".

Answer (score 1):

i think it should look like this:

```
jobs:
- job: xxx   
  strategy:
    parallel: 8 # parallel strategy, see below
    maxParallel: 3 # maximum number of agents to simultaneously run copies of this job on
```

Comment: Running this way will get the error: `Unexpected value 'maxParallel'`. This might be a bug in the Azure DevOps yaml schema

Comment: ugh, sorry, I had a mispaste, can you try this?

Comment: yeah, I tried and it still doesn't work. Does that syntax work for you? I'm wondering if this is just not supported...

Comment: I'll test today

Comment: I emailed to folks at Azure DevOps, and it's a bug... They're working on fixing it